# Get JSON Object property?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get the property information for 'Kind' in the JSON data here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/29bj6h/how_to_learn_javascript_properly/.json

I'm currently just getting 18 'undefined' printed out to the console.

Where am I going wrong?

Cheers

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var jsonData = $.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/29bj6h/how_to_learn_javascript_properly/.json');

        for(var key in jsonData) {
            console.log(key.kind);
        }
});
```

Comment: Look closer at the structure of the JSON. I can already see that the entire thing is wrapped in an array so your result will be in jsonData[0] at least.

Comment: printing only key shows 18 keys console.log(key); rather key.kind

Comment: check the var jsonData if you are getting the response from getJSON or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (more specifically, a jqXHR object which implements the promise interface), not the results of parsing the HTTP response as JSON.

Additionally, when you iterate over an object with `in`, the values you get will be the names of the properties as strings. These don't have `kind` properties.

To get to `kind` you need to read the **value**, not the property name.

It's best to avoid `in` for arrays though. `forEach` is usually a better approach.

```js
function processResponse(parsed_data) {
    parsed_data.forEach(processItem)
}

function processItem(current_value) {
    console.log(current_value.kind);  
}

var jqXHR = $.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/29bj6h/how_to_learn_javascript_properly/.json');

jqXHR.done(processResponse);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Quentin,

thanks for the detailed reply I appreciate it.

My JS is pretty basic to be fair, I've only done the Codecademy JS course.

I haven't learnt AJAX yet.

I just wanted to try and make a simple app using JS.

Do you think I should learn AJAX first? Or whatever pre-requisites do you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: @JoeConsterdine — Since you're trying to use Ajax … yes, you should learn it.

Comment: I thought it just JQuery haha.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is to be written as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jsonData = $.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/29bj6h/how_to_learn_javascript_properly/.json', function(jsonData) {
       $.each( jsonData, function( key, val ) {
         console.log(val.kind);
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the success callback argument in to getJson function.
Like the Snippet below

```
var jsonData = $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/29bj6h/how_to_learn_javascript_properly/.json', function(response) {
        response.forEach(function(key) {
          console.log(key.kind)
        })
      });
```

[Check this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VarunG/pjufa1g5/)

Answer (score -2):

printing only the key showing the result not undefined. As you only taking the key, it shows key.

```
for(var key in jsonData) {
    console.log(key);
}
```